# highcharts yaxis hours as actual hours not days

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mW9XD/

I'm struggling to get the amount of hours on the yaxis to actually show as the amount of hours rather than slip into days.  The example shows that after 24 hours it slips into being the 2nd of Jan rather than 25 or 26 hours.

my yaxis code looks somewhat like:

```
yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                 hour: '%H:%M:%S'
            },
            title: {
                 text: 'Hours'
            },
            min: 1000,
            startOnTick: false,
            showFirstLabel: false
        },
```

How can i get it to display the amount of hours rather than hours/days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my yAxis to look like this:

```
yAxis: {
           type: 'linear',
           labels:{
               formatter: function(){
                    var seconds = (this.value/ 1000) | 0;
                    this.value -= seconds * 1000;

                    var minutes = (seconds / 60) | 0;
                    seconds -= minutes * 60;

                    var hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
                    minutes -= hours * 60;
                    return hours;
                }
           },
           title: {
               text: 'Hours'
           },
           min: 1000,
           startOnTick: false,
           showFirstLabel: false
      },
```

Works how i want it to, wish it were a bit more native though.